# Creating a simple link to the Play store from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to link to the play store, with no luck, each time I use this code;

```
market://search?q=pub:"+devName and http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:"+devName
```

It is taking the // and commenting out the rest of the code! How do I get Eclipse to ignore the // as all it is doing is keeping the

```
market:
```

And the rest of the code is commented out because it thinks the // is trying to ignore the text.

If I use this;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

It puts an error on startActivity saying it is undefined for the type 'myApp.java'

Comment: You didn't forget the opening part of the string indicator, did you, by that I mean "http://..."

Comment: It's a market link not a http link, but even if I wanted http:// it would still treat the // as commenting out the rest

Comment: Yeah, but if it's a string, it shouldn't take it as a comment after you close the string.

Comment: I updated the question, a little further...But still not working :(

Comment: What class is this? Is this an activity? startActivity() is a function of Context.

Comment: I am not sure I am following... What do you mean?  It is an options screen called options.java and in that screen I have;

`public void goToStore(Object sender){
//this is what I want to link to the store
}`

Comment: MyApp.java, what is the class of MyApp.java? Is does this extend from Activity, is this actually a subclass of Context?

Comment: public class myApp extends CCLayer
{

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55661/discussion-between-user3355723-and-zhuinden).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your class extends from CCLayer, it needs a class that extends from Context in order to start an Activity using an Intent.

Therefore, you need to use the following code:

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```